# Why does a zero-element width cause its parent to scroll, and how can I prevent this?

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

**TLDR:**

In the following example, why does the `container` have scrollbars, and how can I prevent scrollbars from appearing unless the actual contents of `.contents` need them (as opposed to `contents::after`).

```css
.container { /* container may be too narrow for its contents, so scrolling is sometimes desired */
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: pre;
  width: 15rem;
}

.contents { /* contents are centered in container */
  background: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 7rem;
}

.contents::after { /* dots are nonessential, shouldn't affect centering, and shouldn't cause scrolling */
  content: "....................................";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="contents"> centered </span>
</div>
```

**The backstory, in case there's a better workaround:**

I have a centered line of text in a container.  If the text is wider than the container, the container should support scrolling (`overflow: auto`); something like this (`<-======--------------->` is a scrollbar):

```
[     short message     ]
```

```
[onger message, scrolli]
<-======--------------->
```

Sometimes, to indicate that a process is running, I add a little animation after the text: `.`, `..`, `...`; like this:

```
[     short message.    ]
[     short message..   ]
[     short message...  ]
```

Of course, the text should remain centered when the number of dots changes (it shouldn't move), so I put `width: 0` on the dots.

I don't want the dots themselves to cause scrolling, but they do:  I see this:

```
[essage that has dots..]
<-======--------------->
```

instead of this:

```
[message that has dots.]
```

It seems that setting the `...` element to `width: 0` is not enough to give it a 0 `scrollWidth` or `offsetWidth` (just a 0 `clientWidth`).

**How do I prevent one specific element from adding scrollbars to its parent?**

Comment: Maybe `overflow:hidden;` on the `.contents` ?

Comment: in your real use cas it's only 3 dots animating? or you can go to many like you are showing?

Comment: Just the three dots, but I'd like to understand what's happening.  And even with thre dots it's an issue because the scrollbar keeps changing length when the content is longer than the container.

Comment: because dots are a part of the overflowing content so they trigger the scrollbar

Comment: Yes, but their width is 0

Comment: there is still an overflow, it's about the dots here not their container which is 0. This is the logic of overlow: the content is outside its container and will trigger the scroll

Comment: read this to understand: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#scrollable .. note the part saying : *the scrollable overflow areas of all of the above boxes (accounting for transforms as described above), provided they themselves have overflow: visible* and the above boxes are *all boxes for which it is the containing block*

Answer (score 1):

make the dots `position:absolute` without making any of the container `position:relative` then you add a `clip-path` to clip the extra overflow

```css
.container { 
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: pre;
  width: 15rem;
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% 100%,0 100%);
}

.contents { 
  background: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
}

.contents::after {
  position:absolute;
  content: attr(data-dots);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
}

/* hover to see the effect of the clip-path*/
.container:hover {
  clip-path:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="contents" data-dots=".......................... you will not see me"> centered </span>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span class="contents" data-dots=".."> centered </span>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span class="contents" data-dots=".... you will not see me"> long centered content that will trigger the scroll</span>
</div>
```

Comment: There would still be overflow if the screen is narrower than the longest string, better hide the overflow on the body

Comment: @ZohirSalak true but I don't think it's an issue in his case since he will be using only 3 dots at max and only during the animation.

Comment: Yes that is the idea, Since this isn't really a necessity to solve the op's issue, i thought i'd leave the heads up for future readers

Comment: Ah, clip-path is a nice idea as well!

Answer (score 1):

An idea would be to flip the container, using `transform` or `direction` properties and `absolute` position to manipulate the placement

---

**direction**

recommended

```css
.container {
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: pre;
  width: 15rem;
  border: 1px solid;
  direction: rtl;
}

.contents {
  direction: ltr;
  background: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.contents::before {
  content: '..................................';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><span class="contents"> centered </span>
</div>
```

---

**transform**

Drawback blurry text on scroll.

```css
.container {
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: pre;
    width: 15rem;
    border: 1px solid;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.contents {
    background: lightblue;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.contents::before {
  content: '..................................';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><span class="contents"> centered </span>
</div>
```

---

**Drawback**

Drawback is a flipped scrollbar for long strings

**transform**

```css
.container {
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: pre;
  width: 15rem;
  border: 1px solid;
  direction: rtl;
}

.contents {
  background: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  direction: ltr;
}

.contents::before {
  content: '..................................';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><span class="contents"> Really long string that causes parent to overflow </span>
</div>
```

Comment: These are all interesting options.    One drawback of the direction approach is that the text gets selected right to left.

Comment: @Clément You can select both ways ?

Comment: If you select just the text, it's LTR; but if you include the box around it, it's RTL, right?

Answer (score -2):

Try setting the parent container to

```
overflow: hidden
```